# How to extract href value from anchor tag with no ID

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is the best way to grab the `href` value from the anchor tag with the anchor tag has no id. It looks like this:

```
<a href="www.google.com">mydoc.pdf</a>
```

Usually I would use getElementById, but can't in this case. I also tried getElementsByTagName, but since there are so many on the page it would be impossible.

Comment: It depends on the rest of the markup on the page. This is not enough information.

Comment: There could be another 100 anchor tags on the page @Unmitigated

Comment: So what is the criteria by which you are choosing this specific anchor element? Is there anything that distinguishes it from all the other anchors?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, your tag does not have a unique value to query like id, name, ...

If you know it's index or "mydoc.pdf" you can get it.

Sample:

```js
var atags = document.getElementByTagName("a");
var selectedByIndex = atags[index];
var selectedbyText = atags.filter(function(tag,index) {
return tag.innerHTML === "mydoc.pdf";
});
```

Comment: What is the variable 'index' used in: atags[index]?